# Saving figures in a loop

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, ipython

I don't know if this is possible and I hope to acurally portray what I wish to accomplish.

Say we have:

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

y = 2

for x in xrange(0,5):
    value = [1,int(y)]
    plt.plot(value)
    plt.savefig("value" + y + ".png")
    y+=1
```

So my goal here is to get 5 plots (or I think this would give me 6 plots), but I want them to each save with different names so they don't overwrite each time it goes through the loop. Is this possible?

Note: The numbers and values in this example are arbitrary. My hope is just to plot in a loop like this and have a dynamic method to save the name of the figure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `y`, just use the `x` in your loop.

```
for x in xrange(1,6): # starts at 1 and goes to 5
    print ("value" + str(x) + ".png")
value1.png
value2.png
value3.png
value4.png
value5.png
```

Answer (score 5):

You can not add a string (e.g. `"value"`) and an int (e.g. `y`). Attempting to do so raises a `TypeError`. Use string formatting instead:

```
plt.savefig("value{y}.png".format(y=y))
```